# How to include from multiple directories

Tags: php, css, include, subdirectory

My header.php file contains the .css for my project. I've made a new page that is a few directories in. (root/mods/people/employees/addemployee.php)

If i put the file in the root, the css works fine. If I put it where I want it, the css doesn't appear.

Is there a way around this? Im trying to keep things organized.

**Add Employee Code:**

```
<?php include("../../../includes/layouts/header.php"); ?>


<div id="main">
    <div id="subnavigation">
        <?php
            include('../../../mods/main_menu/index.html');
        ?>

    </div>

  <div id="page">


            <p>Add Employee!</p>




</div>
  </div>
</div>

<?php include("../../../includes/layouts/footer.php"); ?>
```

**Header.php Code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Company H&S Site </title>
        <link href="stylesheets/public.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="header">


      <h1>H&S Site </h1>


    </div>
```

Comment: Get you an error? `404` or `500`?

Comment: No error, i just dont get any css formatting. 

If I go to my header and add some ../ it works, but then my main page losses it's formatting instead.

Comment: Have you try with absolute url for your css-style? Like: `http://example.com/stylesheets/public.css` - and have a look to this [chdir()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chdir.php)

Comment: using the absolute works, but when i go live I would have to edit every single link on the website. It would take forever and be a huge mess!

Comment: Why you have to edit every single file? Then you're doing something wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is these headache inducing `../../../` relative path calls. Instead I recommend you set a default base path and never worry about stuff like this again:

```
<?php
$BASE_PATH = '/the/path/to/the/codebase/';
include_once($BASE_PATH . "includes/layouts/header.php");
?>

<div id="main">
    <div id="subnavigation">
        <?php
            include_once($BASE_PATH . "mods/main_menu/index.html");
        ?>

    </div>

  <div id="page">


            <p>Add Employee!</p>
</div>
  </div>
</div>

<?php include_once($BASE_PATH . "includes/layouts/footer.php"); ?>
```

If you don’t know the base path to your files, then place this line at the top of your PHP code:

```
echo "Your path is: " . realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) . "<br />";
```

And load that page. Somewhere near the top should be a line that reads:

> Your path is: /the/path/to/the/codebase/

Of course `/the/path/to/the/codebase/` will be your actual file path, but that will be your base path. Then just set `$BASE_PATH` to that value.

By setting a hard-coded base path with `$BASE_PATH` you always know where your code is located & can place your pages anywhere in a directory structure with ease.

I would also recommend using [`include_once`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php) instead of [`include`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) to avoid scenarios where your script might inadvertently attempt to load the same file more than once.

```
include_once($BASE_PATH . "includes/layouts/header.php");
```

Comment: do I run the code to display the base path on the page im working with? or on the index of the main site?

my basepath for the page im working is: C:\xampp\htdocs\OGS\mods\people\employees, which when concatenated with the include, results in an error.

My main index.php would result in the same error, but with the base path of: C:\xampp\htdocs\OGS\

Comment: It works now, but I had to change all my forwards and backslashes. Thanks!

Comment: Now, could I not make this a function so that when I upload to a live server I just have to modify the basepath on one file, and not a bunch of separate ones?

Comment: I need a few more points before I can up vote apparently. Hopefully I will have enough soon and can come back and up vote!